# How can I check if my function is called with input from a pipe?

Tags: bash

I usually use `if [ -t 0 ]` to test stdin and `if [ -t 1 ]` to see if stdin and stdout are TTY's, and if they aren't I assume that they're pipes.  I recently learned that that is a bad assumption:

```
function context()
{
    if [ -t 0 ]
    then
        if [ -t 1 ]
        then
            echo "no pipes"
        else
            echo "pipe out only"
        fi
    else
        if [ -t 1 ]
        then
            echo "pipe in only"
        else
            echo "pipe in and out"
        fi
    fi
}

echo "No Loop:"        # these cases work as desired
context
echo 'f' | context
echo 'f' | context | cat
context | cat

echo
echo "Loop:"
echo $'foo
bar' | while read x
do
    context             # I want this to say "no pipes"
    echo 'f' | context
done
```

The output of the above bash is this:

```
No Loop:
no pipes
pipe in only
pipe in and out
pipe out only

Loop:
pipe in only
pipe in only
pipe in only
pipe in only
```

How can I change the definition of `context` to so that the 5th and 7th calls print "no pipes"?

That is, rather than testing whether stdin is not a terminal (which causes the problem) I'd like to test whether stdin for this particular function happens to be a pipe.  I see that `-p` checks to see if it's a named pipe, but I want this for anonymous pipes.

**Edit**

The actual use case involves a function we'll call `theDb` in the place of `context`.  Ideally the two cases below would be equivalent regardless of context:

```
cat file_with_some_sql | theDb
theDb "sql goes here"
```

Comment: why should that say "no pipes" while its stdin is, in fact, a pipe? but, yes, it's a silly assumption that everything not a tty is a pipe -- what about regular files? character devices? (eg. `context <<<'' >/dev/null`).

Comment: Is this a purely academic question or is there a real problem you are trying to solve by checking this?  The academic question is interesting, but the broad answer is "no, there is no *easy* way."  While there may be an academic solution that is of interest for learning purposes, it's not likely to have practical value in writing a simple shell script.

Comment: @Wildcard there's a real problem.  My .bashrc contains functions that wrap calls to mysql (they supply hostnames, creds, etc), sometimes I I have queries in a file, so I pipe them to the desired function.  Other times I type the queries on the command line.  This works great, until I include it in a loop.

Comment: You seem to assume that in eg. `cat ~/.bashrc | while read p; do tr a e; done` the output of `cat` is not piped to `tr`. That assumption is false.

Comment: But fwiw, in linux `test -p /dev/stdin` works with "anonymous" pipes: `echo yup | if [ -p /dev/stdin ]; then echo yes; fi`

Comment: If you needed to distinguish pipes from other types of files, on Linux, you could use `-p` as long as you give a path to the pipe, such as `/dev/stdin`. However, that will still tell you that the input to the loop is a pipe, since it is, in fact, a pipe. I don't see any connection between the unsolvable problem you originally posted and the “actual use case” that you added later.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The reason *"pipe in only"* appears four times is in fact because the `context` function is working correctly, and the `echo $'foo bar' | while read x` *etc.* is a pipe -- **everything** in the `while` loop is getting input from a pipe.   To get the desired output, change the `while` loop to a `for` loop, and don't pipe anything to that `for` loop:

```
for x in foo bar; do  context ;  echo 'f' | context; done
```

Output:

```
no pipes
pipe in only
no pipes
pipe in only
```

To show where the OP code went wrong, just pipe something into the `for` loop, and see what happens:

```
echo | for x in foo bar; do  context ;  echo 'f' | context; done
```

Output:

```
pipe in only
pipe in only
pipe in only
pipe in only
```

A novice might (incorrectly) suppose that `while read x` consumes all of standard input, but that is not necessarily so.  Consider this example, with a `read` inside a `while` loop:

```
printf '%s\n' foo bar baz buzz | 
while read x; do echo $x; read y; echo ${y^^} ;done
```

Output:

```
foo
BAR
baz
BUZZ
```